# How to catch the HTTP POST request sent by a Shopify Webhook in salesforce Or import real time data from shopify to salesforce custom orders

Tags: community, rest-api, integration, e-commerce

I wanted to upload real time order details from shopify to salesforce. I found this could be done by using third party apps like onesaas. But I am struggling with the lack of customization it offers.Next option was to use apexclass.

Using apex class I was able to import existing order data to salesforce. But I am struggling to import a real time order. I could initiate a webhook at shopify but salesforce doesn't seems to catch the data without proper authorization :- hearder information. Shopify doesn't allow to add this header info (Authorization: Bearer access_token) of salesforce to its webhook.

Is there a work around here. My primary goal is to import real time data from shopify to salesforce custom orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive webhooks on Salesforce, you can set up a public Site, and then expose an Apex REST service via that site. Obviously, you then have to be careful about making sure that the messages you receive on that service are from the right place. It works well, though. I've used it for many systems, including payments systems.

Here's a link with a walkthrough on setting up a public Site and getting the permissions right for your Apex class:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

Comment: This is good enough. Here is the link that helped me to have more understanding on this . https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites

Thanks Aiden, you saved my day.